# Delphi 10. Debugger notification. Execution error

Tags: debugging, notifications, delphi-10-seattle

Unfortunately, I did not understand the Delphi settings. I have a runtime error (wrong file name for reading data), but the problem is that I only see the error message in debugger mode. If I run the program without a debugger, then the program just stops and does not give an error. How to fix it?

Comment: This mean that code somewhere catch exception and just ignore it. Try to catch exception in debug and check all stack of call for `try..except` blocks. Also check `Application.OnException` event.

Comment: How do you see the error message in the debugger? Does the debugger stops or do you see it in the message pane? If it stops, it is likely on the line where the error occurs. If you need more help, you need to give more details (For that purpose, you must [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73356242/edit) your post, not add a comment).